# Gekko feasible in smaller problem while infeasible in larger problem

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve the problem as follows with Gekko in python.
I_s is an indicator variable in the problem whose value is 1 if theta is positive and 0 if theta is zero.
[image]

I wrote the problem in a code using Gekko, python.

In contrast to my previous posts, I add some constraints with respect to I, which is an indicator variable.

If I set N=10, the solution, theta is all zero, which is the result that I want.

But if I set N=100 or 200, the solution cannot be found. I cannot understand why this happens.

I want to check if theta is also zero in larger N (200).

Is there any way to solve this issue?

My code is as belows.

```
# Import package
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Define parameters
P_CO = 600                      # $/tonCO
beta_CO2 = 1                    # no unit
P_CO2 = 80                      # $/tonCO2eq
E_ref = 3.1022616               # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_dir = -1.600570692            # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_others = 0.3339226804   # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_elec_cons = 18.46607256 # GJ/tonCO
C1_CAPEX = 285695               # no unit
C2_CAPEX = 188.42               # no unit
C1_FOX = 82282                  # no unit
C2_FOX = 24.094                 # no unit
C1_ROX = 4471.5                 # no unit
C2_ROX = 96.034                 # no unit
C1_UOX = 7934.9                 # no unit
C2_UOX = 986.9                  # no unit
r = 0.08                        # discount rate
N = 10                         # number of scenarios
T = 30                          # total time period
GWP_init = 0.338723235          # 2020 Electricity GWP in EU 27 countries
theta_max = 1600000             # Max capacity

# Function to make GWP_EU matrix (TxN matrix)
def Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, n_years, num_episodes):

    GWP_mean = 0.36258224*np.exp(-0.16395611*np.arange(1, n_years+2)) + 0.03091272
    GWP_mean = GWP_mean.reshape(-1,1)
    GWP_Yearly = np.tile(GWP_mean, num_episodes) 

    noise = np.zeros((n_years+1, num_episodes))
    stdev2050 = GWP_mean[-1] * 0.25 
    stdev = np.arange(0, stdev2050 * (1 + 1/n_years), stdev2050/n_years)

    for i in range(n_years+1):
        noise[i,:] = np.random.normal(0, stdev[i], num_episodes) 

    GWP_forecast = GWP_Yearly + noise 

    return GWP_forecast

GWP_EU = Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, T, N) # (T+1)*N matrix
GWP_EU = GWP_EU[1:,:] # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(GWP_EU))

# Build Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
theta = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0, ub=theta_max)
I = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)
demand = np.ones((T,1))
demand[0] = 8031887.589
for k in range(1,11):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.026 
for k in range(11,21):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.016
for k in range(21,T):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.011 
demand = 0.12 * demand
demand = np.tile(demand, N) # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(demand))

m3 = [[m.min3(demand[t,s],theta[s]) for t in range(T)] for s in range(N)]
obj = m.sum([sum([((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m3[s][t]) \
            + (beta_CO2*P_CO2*m3[s][t]*(E_ref-E_dir-E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s])) \
            - (C1_CAPEX*I[s]+C2_CAPEX*theta[s]+C1_FOX*I[s]+C2_FOX*theta[s])\
            - (C1_ROX*I[s]+C2_ROX*m3[s][t]+C1_UOX*I[s]+C2_UOX*m3[s][t])) for t in range(T)]) for s in range(N)])
for i in range(N):
    m.Equation(theta[i]<=1000000*I[i])
    m.Equation(-theta[i]<1000000*(1-I[i]))

# obj = m.sum([m.sum([((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
#             + (beta_CO2*P_CO2*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])*(E_ref-E_dir-E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s])) \
#             - (C1_CAPEX+C2_CAPEX*theta[s]+C1_FOX+C2_FOX*theta[s])-(C1_ROX+C2_ROX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])+C1_UOX+C2_UOX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s]))) for t in range(T)]) for s in range(N)])
m.Maximize(obj/N)
m.solve(disp=True)   

# s = m.sum(m.sum(((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
#             + beta_CO2*P_CO2*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])*(E_ref-E_dir-E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s]) \
#             - (C1_CAPEX + C2_CAPEX*theta[s]) - (C1_FOX + C2_FOX*theta[s]) - (C1_ROX + C2_ROX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) - (C1_UOX + C2_UOX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])))
#     for s in range(N)) for t in range(T))/N
         
print(theta)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by increasing the big M in the constraint for an indicator variable I, 1000000 to 10000000.

```
for i in range(N):
    m.Equation(theta[i]<=10000000*I[i])
    m.Equation(-theta[i]<10000000*(1-I[i]))
```

I didn't understand why this worked, but the result gave me the solution of 200*1 array with all zero.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a successful solution. With a bigger constant, it may be meeting a convergence tolerance that is a relative 1e-6. Try tightening the solver tolerance to `m.options.RTOL=1e-8` and `m.options.OTOL=1e-8` to see if you still get a successful solution. One reason why it may not converge is the random number generator that could be generating cases that aren't feasible.

Comment: @JohnHedengren Oh that can be the reason I didn't notice it. Also, I tried `m.options.RTOL=1e-8` and `m.options.OTOL=1e-8` and got the same result. Did that mean I can be sure that I got the successful solution?

Comment: A successful solution report by the solver indicates that the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions are satisfied to the specified tolerance: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker